# Printing echo command only once at loop start

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following loop:

```
for k in "${keys[@]}"; do
    if output=$(curl -s -f \
    --max-time 5 \
    "https://api.site/info?key=$k"); then
    printf "\n\n%s\n$(json_pp<<<"$output")\n\n" "$k"
    fi
done
```

I want to printing echo command only once at loop start.

And it is clear that this option will print the "info endpoint" line many times instead of one:

```
for k in "${keys[@]}"; do
    echo 'info endpoint:'
    if output=$(curl -s -f \
    --max-time 5 \
    "https://api.site/info?key=$k"); then
    printf "\n\n%s\n$(json_pp<<<"$output")\n\n" "$k"
    fi
done
```

Please give me the right direction, thx.

Comment: Why not print it before the loop?

Comment: As @Maroun said, you should print it out before the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Simply put it outside the loop:

```
echo 'info endpoint:'
for k in "${keys[@]}"; do
  if output=$(curl -s -f \
  --max-time 5 \
  "https://api.site/info?key=$k"); then
  printf "\n\n%s\n$(json_pp<<<"$output")\n\n" "$k"
  fi
done
```

If it is important to you that it is inside, you could add an if statement to conditionally call it only on the first run (based on the key, or a new variable)